# How to create executable single jar which include webapp resources by sbt-assembly with scalatra

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra, sbt-assembly

I'm making webapp using scalatra framework via sbt & xsbt-web-plugin.

I want to package all resources(templates, css, js) into a single jar.

In sbt with sbt-assembly plugin, `assembly` command makes single jar which includes all of project's dependencies.

`$ java -jar myproject.jar`

and I open it in browser

> Could not load resource: [/WEB-INF/views/index.scaml]; are you sure it's within [null]?

I unzipped jar to confirm that it does not include `src/main/webapp/*`.

How can I config sbt for including `src/main/webapp/*` and building executable jar?

Comment: almost solved. http://groups.google.com/group/scalatra-user/browse_thread/thread/e07312ff12ac6b79

Answer (score 4):

Resources are meant to be put under the `resources` folders.  There are two such folders:

- `src/main/resources` for resources available at runtime
- `src/test/resources` for resources available only during testing

sbt will package those automatically for you when you run `package-war` or `test`. The project does not need to have the assembly plugin for sbt to include resources.

In your case, you should put the `WEB-INF` directory in `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/`.