# sbt-assembly: How do I include the static files in src/main/webapp

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbtassembly from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly with this merge strategy:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
    case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

For some reason my static content is not being included in the executable jar, but my webservices work fine (so it does work).

How can I include my index.html and javascript files?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How to create executable single jar which include webapp resources by sbt-assembly with scalatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374174/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a related question [Why sbt compile doesn't copy unmanaged resources to classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566474/) that you can get an idea for the setting.

Here's the setting using sbt 0.13:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += { baseDirectory.value / "src/main/webapp" }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was assuming it was an sbtassembly problem. Tomorrow I will test if it was an sbt issue.

Comment: You put me on the correct path, I ended up succeeding with: resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src/main/webapp")