# How to access resources generated by sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

Here's part of my build.sbt:

```
Project(...)... 
  .settings(...,
    resourceGenerators in Compile += myTask.taskValue, 
    mappings in (Compile, packageSrc) += { 
      ((resourceManaged in Compile).value / fileName) -> fileName 
    }
  )
```

Basically, I want to load this file at runtime -- how do I do that/where do I look for it?

I'm using sbt-assembly to package stuff up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sbt-assembly: How do I include the static files in src/main/webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502894/sbt-assembly-how-do-i-include-the-static-files-in-src-main-webapp). I think you can access generated resources same way as normally, so your question is about including them in the assembly jar.